# How to hide class="<?php print $example;?>" CSS

Tags: php, css

I would like to hide this link using CSS:

```
<a href="<?php print $edit_link_location;?>"    class="<?php print $activelocation;?>">    <?php esc_html_e('Location','wpestate');?></a>
```

The idea was to hide by its class like:

```
.class {
display:none;
}
```

But there is the PHP that is confusing me.

How can I hide this? Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there is the PHP that is confusing me.

PHP is simply printing the `$activelocation` variable/string out to your output (HTML). The problem is that `$activelocation` could be anything. We don't see the entire PHP script in your question, nor do I want to.

I would check the output/source ("View Source"/use Web Inspector) of the page, to see what PHP prints as the class name on your link and then hide/`display:none` that class.

Example: You look in the source/output and find `<a href="/php/made/this/edit_link_location" class="php_also_made_this">` Now you can go ahead and hide the class "`.php_also_made_this`"

```
.php_also_made_this { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Just be careful. The class `.php_also_made_this` might be used elsewhere and you might be hiding things that you don't want to!

Comment: <a href="link" class="">    Location</a>

Comment: I just realised that this class is for active links only.

<a href="http://www.tamarindoactive.com/edit-listing/?listing_edit=1678&amp;action=location" class="user_tab_active">    Location</a>

Comment: That's probably why PHP is used here. The logic inside the PHP script can choose when to apply the class `.user_tab_active` and apply it only to the links that are "active".

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `$activelocation` variable pass the name of class.

```
 <a href="<?php print $edit_link_location;?>"    class="<?php echo $activelocation;?>">    <?php esc_html_e('Location','wpestate');?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

In php

```
if ($isActive) {
    $activelocation = 'active';
} else {
    $activelocation = 'notactive';
}
```

and in your css

```
/* hide elements with class = 'notactive' */
.notactive {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the $activelocation php variable to the string "class". Then it should hide your link. $activelocation = "class";